# Моргания и откат при прокрутке виртуализации скролла

Tags: css, reactjs, scss, прокрутка

Сделал виртуализацию скролла, но при использовании совместно с

```
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
```

Подскажите плиз кто знает как можно решить проблему.
Вот код

```
import {memo, MutableRefObject, ReactNode, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {classNames} from "shared/lib/classNames/classNames";
import {useQuery} from "@apollo/client";
import {GET_VEHICLES} from "shared/api/GET_VEHICLES";
import {useDataContext} from "features/DataContext";
import cls from "./CardShip.module.scss"
import {Vehicle} from "entity/Vehicle";

interface CardShipProps {
    className?: string
    children?: ReactNode
}


export const CardShip = memo((props: CardShipProps) => {

    const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(GET_VEHICLES);

    const {dataSort, setDataSort} = useDataContext()

    const [startSlice, setStartSlice] = useState(0)

    const rootRef = useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>


    const rowShips = 330
    const visibleShips = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / rowShips) * 8

    const getBottomHeight = () => {
        // console.log(rowShips,dataSort.length,startSlice)


        return (rowShips + 30) * (dataSort && dataSort.length - (startSlice + visibleShips+1))
    }
    const getTopHeight = () => {
        console.log(rowShips, startSlice)
        return (rowShips + 30) * startSlice
    }

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     console.log(getTopHeight(), startSlice)
    // }, [getTopHeight, startSlice]);


    useEffect(() => {
        function onScroll(e: any) {
            setStartSlice(
                Math.floor(e.target.scrollTop / (rowShips + 30))
            );

        }

        rootRef.current && rootRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

        return () => {
            rootRef.current && rootRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
        }
    }, [visibleShips, rowShips]);


    const {
        className,
        children,
        ...otherProps
    } = props
    useEffect(() => {
        if (data?.vehicles) {
            setDataSort(data.vehicles)
        }

    }, [data]);


    return (
        <div
            className={classNames("", {}, [className])}
            style={{height: (rowShips + 30) * visibleShips, overflow: 'auto'}}
            ref={rootRef}
            {...otherProps}
        >
            <div className={cls.top} style={{height: getTopHeight()}}/>
            <div className={cls.CardShip}>
                {dataSort && dataSort.slice(startSlice, startSlice + visibleShips).map((vehicle: Vehicle, index: number) => (
                        <div className={cls.cardWrapper} style={{height: rowShips, margin: "30px"}}
                             key={startSlice + index}>
                            <div className={cls.title}>{vehicle.title}</div>
                            <img className={cls.flag} src={`https:${vehicle.nation.icons.large}`}/>
                            <img className={cls.ship} src={`https:${vehicle.icons.medium}`}/>
                            <div className={cls.type}>{vehicle.type.name}</div>
                            <div className={cls.nation}>{vehicle.nation.name}</div>
                            <div className={cls.level}>{vehicle.level}</div>
                            <div className={cls.description}>{vehicle.description}</div>
                        </div>
                    )
                )}

            </div>
            <div style={{height: getBottomHeight(), width:"100vw"}}/>
        </div>
    );
});
```

Вот стили

```
.CardShip {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.top{
    background-color: red;
    width: 1000px;
}
.bottom{
    width: 1000px;
}

.cardWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 440px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;

}

.ship {
    z-index: 100;
    position: inherit;
}

.flag {
    width: 310px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 70px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.title {
    font-family: var(--font-title);
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 43px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #b2b5ba;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 80px;

}

.description {
    font-family: var(--font-description);
    color: #b2b5ba;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.type {
    font-family: var(--font-title);
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 43px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #b2b5ba;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 270px;
    left: 180px;

}

.nation {
    font-family: var(--font-title);
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 43px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #b2b5ba;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 80px;

}

.level {
    font-family: var(--font-title);
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 43px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #b2b5ba;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 270px;
    left: 80px;

}
```

Еще раз обращу внимание, что если отключить стили .CardShip то все работает плавно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему просто не скрыть скроллбар? Почему вам потребовалось за браузер делать его работу?